# Error while loading shared libraries: libsigc-2.0.so versus libsigc-2.0.so.0

Tags: linux

I'm building an application that uses libsigc-2.0 ( -lsigc-2.0 )

I'm getting a runtime error because the application cannot find libsigc-2.0.so.0

```
error while loading shared libraries: libsigc-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file
```

However, my system only has libsigc-2.0.so:

```
ls /usr/lib64/libsigc*
/usr/lib64/libsigc-2.0.so
```

Where is my program picking the **.0!!**

I have a couple of theories, but I don't know how to test them efficiently:

- my libsigc-2.0.so is really a libsigc-2.0.so.0, so that's injecting a dependency in my code somehow
- there's another library hidden somewhere. Then again, I did a *find* and nothing showed up
- One of the libraries or archives I use has that dependency

I can fix the problem if I add libsigc-2.0.so.0, but that feels like a hack to me (and I wouldn't understand what's happening)

**Edit 1**
Thanks for your suggestions. After using ldd, as expected, the executable is bound to libsigc-2.0.so.0, but it's not finding it at runtime

```
libsigc-2.0.so.0 => not found
```

using LD_DEBUG=all , all the paths to load are shown. libsigc-2.0.so.0 is not found in any of them (but libsigc-2.0.so is)

Finally, using -v threw a lot of library paths (-L) I did a script to look for libsigc-2.0.so.0 in all of them, but it didn't show (again, libsigc-2.0.so did).

This is the link command shown at the very end (I'm using an intel compiler -> icpc):

```
icpc -m64 -gcc -o convert.linux-intel O.linux-intel/convert.o 
-L/pathToProject/Executive/lib/linux-intel -lExecutive 
-L/home/nhcuzot/projects/3.1/dev/Ports/lib/linux-intel -lStdPorts -Wl,-E 
-L/pathToProject/util/linux-intel/lib 
-lantlr -lnewmat -ledit_64 -lncurses 
/pathToProject/util/linux-intel/lib/libcrypto.a 
/pathToProject/util/linux-intel/lib/libssl.a 
-pthread -lsigc-2.0 -L/pathToProject/lib 
-L/pathToIntelCompiler/ -lifcore -lncurses -lm -ldl -v
```

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Although this problem is particular to Linux, it is related a C++ program. More specifically, to the linking part (but you always need to link a C++ program). I'm curious: why removing the C++ tag?

Comment: Because there's no specific c++ source code in your question, and how linked libraries are resolved aren't a particular c++ problem, but of your system configuration. The executable might be compiled and linked from any language.

Comment: Can you build with `gcc -v` and post the output? Can you post the output of `ldd ./your_executable` ? Can you run the application like `LD_DEBUG=all ./your_executable` and post the output?

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk. I did as you suggested. So far, I think I didn't get useful information, but then again, I might be missing something (on the compilation perhaps? or maybe one of my archives has a dependency?)

Comment: Especially interesting would be the output of `objdump -p /usr/lib64/libsigc-2.0.so | grep SONAME` .  If that outputs `libsigc-2.0.so.0` then that indicates either a corrupted package installation, or (much less likely) a broken package or broken dependencies.

Comment: And to dump embedded dependencies of all the libraries that are successfully found by the dynamic loader (quick and dirty, has minor issues): `echo convert.linux-intel; objdump -p convert.linux-intel | grep NEEDED; for l in $(ldd ./convert.linux-intel | sed -e 's/.* => \([^ ]*\).*/\1/'); do echo; echo $l; objdump -p $l | grep NEEDED; done`

Comment: @DanielSchepler: that's it. I got  SONAME libsigc-2.0.so.0. Can you add that as a solution so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some basics on how dynamic linking works in ELF executables: at link time, each shared library being linked in has an `SONAME` parameter which gets copied into a `NEEDED` entry in the resulting executable.  Then, at dynamic linking time, the `NEEDED` entries of each executable and dynamic library are processed recursively to determine what files need to be loaded into memory.  (The reason for this is so that you can link in e.g. `libncurses.so` which is a symbolic link to the real library; but in the resulting executable, it embeds the information about the "compatibility version" e.g. `libncurses.so.5` or `libncurses.so.6`.  Then, at dynamic linking time, the dynamic linker `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` looks at these `NEEDED` entries to determine that it needs to load `libncurses.so.5` or `libncurses.so.6` into memory - and this also is typically a symbolic link to the actual library like `libncurses.so.5.9` or `libncurses.so.6.1`.

Now, to see this dependency information for any given ELF object, you can use the `objdump` utility from binutils:

```
objdump -p /usr/lib64/libsigc-2.0.so | grep -E 'SONAME|NEEDED'
```

Presumably, this should show that the `SONAME` entry is `libsigc-2.0.so.0`.  If so, this indicates that the installation of the library package is corrupted.  A couple ways to resolve this would be:

- Use the packaging system to reinstall the appropriate package.  For example, it seems most likely, based on the `/usr/lib64` path, that you're using a YUM/RPM based distribution.  So you might want to search for the package that's supposed to contain a `libsigc-2.0.so.0` symbolic link using something like (untested) `yum whatprovides '*/libsigc-2.0.so.0` and then `sudo yum reinstall libsigc` (obviously substituting whatever the real package name is for `libsigc`).
- Run `sudo ldconfig`.  The `ldconfig` tool recreates missing symbolic links based on `SONAME` entries of libraries in the dynamic linker's search path, and also updates the `/etc/ld.so.cache` file containing a map from the base filenames contained in `NEEDED` entries to full file paths.  This has the disadvantage, however, that `ldconfig` cannot always correctly guess where the missing symbolic links should point, which is why I would prefer trying to reinstall the distribution's library package first.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install following dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 \
libsigc++-2.0-0v5
```